# Zero elements of tensor product of two free modules

Tags: modules, tensor-products, free-modules

I want to find conditions on which $a \otimes b =0 $ implies $a=0 $ or $b=0$.

My thought is followings.

Let $a\otimes b =0$. $R$ be an integral domain.
If $M$ and $N$ are free $R$-modules, $a$ and $ b$ are contained in some finitely generated free submodules $M'$ and $N'$ respectively. For simplicity, let $M'\cong R^m$ and $N' \cong R^n$. If $a= \sum_i^m a_i e_i $ and $b= \sum_j^n b_j f_j$, then $a\otimes b = \sum_{i,j}^{m,n}a_i b_j (e_i \otimes f_j)$. 
Since $R^m \otimes R^n \cong R^{mn}$, $a_i b_j =0$ for all $i,j$. It follows that $a=0$ or $b=0$.

My questions are as follows.

1. Is my approach correct?
2. Is there a better condition?